# Is there a C/C++ project similar to portablepython?

Tags: c++, c

I've searched the internet for this but couldn't find anything useable, I was just wondering if there exists a C/C++ project similar to [portablepython](http://portablepython.com)?

**EDIT**

I guess the question becomes: is there a portable C/C++ compiler I can stick onto a usb key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is an interpreter that can run "scripts" (`.py` files). Therefore portablepython makes sense - if you don't want to install Python everywhere, but still want to run the small Python files. This helps if the target PC doesn't have Python installed (or you can't even do it because of privileges).

For C/C++ this doesn't make much sense as these are compiled languages. Just compile them to executables and you have your "portability".

If you need to "program C/C++ anywhere", just place your favorite compiler and code editor on a USB stick, and you're done. [portableapps](http://portableapps.com) is a nice place to find portable (as in "USB carry-able" applications), and it has [this link](http://portableapps.com/node/219) for a portable C++ IDE/Compiler.

P.S. Python programs can also be bundled into (rather large) executables using tools like py2exe and PyInstaller.

Comment: So if I install a compiler to a usb stick, I should be able to run/build on any computer?

Comment: @dassouki: not so simple, unfortunately. Depends on the OS too. Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, or something else. I've updated the answer pointing to portableapps.com

Answer (score 1):

PortablePython is a python interpreter, and as Eli Bendersky pointed out, you don't need an interpreter to run programs written in C or C++ once it is compiled. OTOH, if what you are looking for is a *compiler* that does not need installation, you can have a look at [Dev-C++ portable](http://sourceforge.net/projects/devcpp-portable/) . (I am assuming you need this to run on windows as most Unix-like OSes have gcc anyway).

Answer (score 1):

There is [tcc](http://bellard.org/tcc/) which has precompiled binaries for windows which you can use from your usb stick. tcc has no support for c++ though.